# How to resolve merge conflict in Generated Code with NetBeans?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, git-merge

I'm currently working on a project in netbeans Java, and both my coworker and I added a label and a textbox around the same place on the form. But, now if we try to pull our modifications we get merges conflict in the auto-generated code of netbeans.

[image: Merge conflicts]

If we try to make modification directly inside the design form, we get an error telling us that the form isn't correct XML, so what should be the correct way to merge Auto-Generated files ?

Comment: Do you need to keep the autogenerated files in the source repository?  Or can you just keep the source that generates them?

Comment: I don't need to keep the autogenerated file on my computer as long as after the merge it works as expected. However, the autogenerated code is inside a non-autogenerated class (Which is the problematic part)

Comment: I think, the is no way to regenerated .form file from scratch, neither other way to correct the .form file by a hard and manualy edit. Have you found better solution ?

Answer (score -1):

1. When merging accept any version (theirs or yours, it doesn't matter)
2. Delete the file
3. Build so the file is regenerated
4. Confirm that both controls are there
5. Finish the merge
6. Be happy

Comment: The removed .form file, isn't regenerated when "Build", the Editors>Design can't be opened.